# Combine an 'in-line IF' (C#) with response.write

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, conditional-operator

in a conventional C# code block:

```
"myInt = (<condition> ? <true value> : <false value>)"
```

but what about use inside an .aspx where I want to response.write conditionally:

```
<% ( Discount > 0 ?  Response.Write( "$" + Html.Encode(discountDto.Discount.FlatOff.ToString("#,###."): "")%>
```

mny thx

Comment: For future reference, it's frequently referred to as "the ternary if operator".

Comment: @Greg: It's actually referred to as the conditional operator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: @Luke In fairness to Greg I have seen it referenced more times as the Ternary operator than the conditional. Conditional is usually referenced when talking about if statements.

Comment: @Luke:  Actual names and frequently used "de facto" names are often different.  :)  I'm far more likely to call "#" a "hash mark" or "number sign" than an "octothorpe" if I'm trying to communicate with people.

Comment: I've heard them called "compact ifs" - 'orrible things - making dodgy open source even more ugly!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's worth understanding what the different markup tags mean within ASP.NET template markup processing:

```
<% expression %>   - evaluates an expression in the underlying page language
<%= expression %>  - short-hand for Response.Write() - expression is converted to a string and emitted
<%# expression %>  - a databinding expression that allows markup to access the current value of a bound control
```

So to emit the value of a ternary expression (err conditional operator) you can either use:

```
<%= (condition) ? if-true : if-false %>
```

or you can writeL

```
<% Response.Write( (condition) ? if-true : if-false ) %>
```

If you were using databound control (like a repeater, for example), you could use the databinding format to evaluate and emit the result:

```
<asp:Repeater runat='server' otherattributes='...'>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <div class='<%# Container.DataItem( condition ? if-true : if-false ) %>'>  content </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

An interesting aspect of the <%# %> markup extension is that it can be used inside of attributes of a tag, whereas the other two forms (<% and <%=) can only be used in tag content (with a few special case exceptions). The example above demonstrates this.

Comment: very much appreciate the extra effort to list different markup tags - could you expand to include an example of the "#"?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can use any of the three `<% %>` variations you mentioned inside a tag attribute. Why would it be restricted to only one of them? Unless you were referring only to tags with the `runat="server"` attribute...

Comment: I should have been clearer. `runat="server"` tags don't support the <%, <%= markup expansions. However, there are exception even to this - for example meta tags do expand these inside <head>.

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like he was wanting <%= %> but was using <% %>, as was I.

Answer (score 9):

```
<%=
    (Discount > 0)
        ? "$" + Html.Encode(discountDto.Discount.FlatOff.ToString("#,###."))
        : ""
%>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put Response.Write around the whole ?:-operation:

```
<% Response.Write( Discount > 0 ? "$" + Html.Encode(discountDto.Discount.FlatOff.ToString("#,###.") : "" ) %>
```